# Python 2.7.11 - 'SetCursorPos' 'Access is denied.'

Tags: python-2.7, winapi, if-statement, for-loop, pywin32

I have some code that sets a cursor position each time it loops.(I've heard this is a poor way to do it, but do not have an alternative method in mind.) Every so often I will get this message in the shell:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mjesionowski\Desktop\ExcelScript\EXTRABETA.py", line 211, in 
    win32api.SetCursorPos((200,95))
error: (5, 'SetCursorPos', 'Access is denied.')

Any help?

Thanks,
Mason J

Comment: Password protected screensaver, system locked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx) enumerates at least two cases where it may fail with something like *access denied*:

> 1. A window should move the cursor only when the cursor is in the window's client area.
> 2. The input desktop must be the current desktop when you call SetCursorPos.

While I'm not sure that Windows is actually enforcing the 1, it may depend on what kind of application has the mouse or the focus: if it is a UAC window, then you are probably forbidden to move the cursor. Likewise if you are in the security desktop (what shows when you do the Ctrl+Alt+Del) or if the station is locked.

My advise, if you insist on doing the `SetCursorPos()` hack, is to ignore the `access denied` errors and hope it just works anyway... more or less.

Comment: The error would occur at 2 different lines of code where I called it.  I added a time.sleep(0.01) before each time I called SetCursorPos and no more errors!  Definitely a case of "I don't know why it works, but oh well."  Thanks for the help.